# std::reduce with std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++17, unordered-map, std

I have an `unordered_map` of `vectors` and I'm trying to use `std::reduce` to get the sum of all values in all vectors in the map. My current functional code (which I want to replace) looks like this:

```
// input is std::unordered_map<std::vector<uint64_t>>
template<typename T>
uint64_t get_map_sum(T& my_map)
{
    uint64_t totalcount = 0;
    for (auto& p : my_map) 
    {
        for (const auto& q : p.second)
            totalcount += q;
    }
    return total_count;
}
```

I'd like to replace this with `std::reduce` to utilize the parallel execution; I thought this would be straight forward as I only needed to replace each loop with a call to `std::reduce`, but this doesn't appear to be working. My attempt is this:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <execution>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdint>
// reduces the vectors
template <typename Iter, typename T>
T get_vector_sum(Iter begin, Iter end, T initial = 0)
{
    return std::reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, begin, end, initial, 
           [&](auto cur, auto prev) { return cur + prev; });
}

// calls get_vector_sum for all vectors and then reduces vector sums
template<typename Iter>
uint64_t get_map_sum(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    return std::reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, begin, end, 0ULL,
            [&](auto prev, auto cur)
            {
                return get_vector_sum<std::vector<uint64_t>::iterator, 
                       uint64_t>(cur.begin(), cur.end(), prev);
                //return get_vector_sum<std::vector<uint64_t>::iterator,
                //       uint64_t>(cur.second.begin(), cur.second.end(), prev);
            });
}
```

With the code above, I get an error message saying `error C2039: 'begin': is not a member of 'std::pair'` referring to the `auto cur` in the lambda inside `get_map_sum`. I initially used `cur` as a `std::pair`, but when I did that I got a different error saying `error C2228: left of '.second' must have class/struct/union`.

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::vector<uint64_t>> in({ 
        {1, std::vector<uint64_t>{1,2,3,4,5} }, 
        {2, std::vector<uint64_t>{1,2,3,4,5}}, 
        {3, std::vector<uint64_t>{1,2,3,4,5}}});

    auto x = get_map_sum(in); // output 45
    auto y = get_map_sum(in.begin(), in.end()); // error

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to use `std::reduce` with maps like this and, if so, what changes do I need to make to get this working?

Comment: I tried to get your [mcve] running in coliru or godbolt but I failed. Without `#include <execution>`, `std::reduce` is not recognized (`#include <numeric>`) didn't help. With `#include <execution>`, the compiler denied as it didn't find it.

Comment: @Scheff you are correct, those online compilers don't fully support C++17. But the includes you mentioned are the only ones required, I added them to my question, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this requirements for **binary_op** of [`std::reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce):

> binary *FunctionObject* that will be applied in unspecified order to the **result of dereferencing the input iterators**, the **results of other binary_op** and **init**.

This implies that the result of your lambda result and init needs to be of the same type as map's value type, i.e., `std::pair<const uint64_t, std::vector<uint64_t>>`.

You would therefore need to perform the outer reduction over values of this type, which would involve construction of new vectors.

---

I have also tried to create an exemplary code as follows:

```
using M = std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::vector<uint64_t>>;
using V = M::value_type;

M in({ {1, std::vector<uint64_t>{1,2,3,4,5}}, 
       {2, std::vector<uint64_t>{1,2,3,4,5}}, 
       {3, std::vector<uint64_t>{1,2,3,4,5}} });

auto p = std::reduce(in.begin(), in.end(), V{}, 
    [](const V& a, const V& b) {
        auto ra = std::reduce(a.second.begin(), a.second.end(), 0UL,
            [](uint64_t i1, uint64_t i2){ return i1 + i2; });
        auto rb = std::reduce(b.second.begin(), b.second.end(), 0UL,
            [](uint64_t i1, uint64_t i2){ return i1 + i2; });
        return V{0, { ra + rb }};
});
```

But it does not compile with GCC due to seemingly missing `std::reduce` implementation and Clang complains about missing copy assignment operator for value type, which is not copy-assignable due to const key: https://wandbox.org/permlink/FBYAhCArtOHvwu8C.

However, in cppreference, the requirements for the value type is only *MoveConstructible*, not *Copy/MoveAssignable*. So, there seems to be an incorrect implementation in libc++.

---

In this exemplary code, I was able to make it working by defning `V` without const as follows:

```
using V = std::pair<uint64_t, std::vector<uint64_t>>;
```

See https://wandbox.org/permlink/lF9VuJwISYXhpBJL.

Comment: Oh, so the unspecified order is referring to the arguments, not the input values? I thought that meant it might shuffle the input values, but it will still always call the binary_op with the result of some previous call (or init the first time) and then one element from the input iterator. I.e. like this F(...F(F(init, *it++), *it++)...)

Comment: @nick The reduction operation needs to be able to perform the binary op on two map elements (key-value pairs) and then to perform the very same operation on the result of its original application. Therefore, the result must have the very same type. BTW, see the updated answer, I added a working example. Though I doubt it would be genearlly efficient, since many new vectors need to be constructed, which involve dynamic memory allocations.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than constructing vectors as the intermediate result, we just need to provide a type implicitly convertible from `M::value_type`.

```
using M = std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::vector<uint64_t>>;

template <typename Iter, typename T>
T par_unseq_sum(Iter begin, Iter end, T initial = 0)
{
    // std::plus is the default reducer
    return std::reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, begin, end, initial);
}

class map_vector_sum
{
public:
    map_vector_sum() : sum(0) {}
    map_vector_sum(M::const_reference elem) : sum(par_unseq_sum(elem.second)) {}

    map_vector_sum& operator+(const map_vector_sum & rhs) { sum += rhs.sum; }

    explicit operator uint64_t() { return sum; }
private:
    uint64_t sum;
}

M in({ {1, std::vector<uint64_t>{1,2,3,4,5}}, 
       {2, std::vector<uint64_t>{1,2,3,4,5}}, 
       {3, std::vector<uint64_t>{1,2,3,4,5}} });

uint64_t sum = par_unseq_sum(in.begin(), in.end(), map_vector_sum());
```